# Getting an error as Test result: Error while integrating with UFT one

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, plugins, cicd, hp-uft

I am trying to integrate Jenkins with the micro Focus UFT one.

Jenkins version: 2.387.3

Micro Focus Application Automation Tools Version7.3

This is the output of the Jenkins job [image: Console Output]

Please help to fix this issue and let me know if any other details are required to fix this issue.

Why I am getting below error

`Specified cast is not valid. Test result: Error`

Is there any configuration required on Micro Focus UFT one related to jenkins.

Any workaround/tweak would be appreciated.